# Is Coulomb written/found on any object/product as its unit?

Tags: charge, si-units, metrology

Today I had physics class and the unit Coulomb made me wonder as to why it was even invented when I don't see it being used anywhere. When I asked where it may be shown just like bulbs have x Watts and y Volts, my teacher told me to search it up, and I did!

But I couldn't find it anywhere.

Please tell me where it might be seen, thanks in advance! :)

(Q = It i.e. charge = current × time, it's SI unit is Coulomb)

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see it beng used anywhere."?

Comment: Also, an SI unit is not invented to be put on commercial products. The unit of charge is extremely unlikely to be appearing on the label of any product by the nature of how things are used and how convenient we found things to be.

Comment: The SI unit is coulomb (note lower case “c”) and symbol C. The reason for this is to avoid confusion between the man Coulomb and the unit coulomb.

Comment: TLDR: As Agnius Vasiliauskas says in an answer below, you could denote the capacity of a battery in coulombs, but it's more convenient to denote it in ampere hours or in milliampere hours. Similar to why the speeometers in our cars are labelled in miles or kilometers per hour instead of meters per second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that you don't find Coulomb label on any product doesn't means that this product isn't based on charge storage. For example, rechargeable Ni battery with label $2000~\text{mAh}$ stores (when fully charged) $7200~\text{C}$ charge or equivalently $10^{22}$ electrons. The reason why battery labeling uses $It$ notation rather than Q is of practical ones. For example, suppose that you have a music player which uses above mentioned battery and when playing music draws from it ~$20~\text{mA}$ current, then you know that at this rate you can listen your favorite music for $(2000 mAh)/(20 mA) = 100~\text{h}$ or 4 days. So it's more convenient to know ASAP, how much time you can support steady current of $x$ amperes using fully charged battery.

In addition, capacitors also stores electric charge. They are used everywhere in electric circuits (your computer motherboard for example). Capacitor, on the other hand is measured by [capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) :
$$ C = \frac QV \tag 1 $$, it's about how much charge it can store given voltage between two terminals. That's why it is measured in Farads, not in Coulombs directly. But, you can calculate capacitor total charge saved.
For example capacitor with capacitance of $4700~ \mu F$ and terminals voltage of $35~V$ will store at it's plates $164~\text{mC}$ charge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It clarified my doubt to a large extent, but could we say that indirectly, coulomb is a unit that's used in objects but just isn't shown since it is not the correct unit?

Comment: Also, Farads is a unit for C = Q/V right? (I'm asking because I'm oblivious to this topic..) And lastly, since charge is used in measuring capacitance, we'd need something to measure that right? Or could you just provide an example on this and clarify the doubt?

Comment: All measurement units are valid as long as it have a valid definition, is countable and can be measured directly or indirectly. What unit(s) & measurements will be chosen to represent the product by the manufacturer, it's not the scientific question, but rather business and/or engineering one. Yes, 1 Farad is 1 Coulomb per 1 Volt electric potential. Yes, charge amount in the system can be measured directly with [Coulombmeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulombmeter). There is even high school labs which are dedicated to capacitor charge measurement, google "TAP 126-2".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Lastly this means that, you use the coulombmeter when you need to check the charge passing through the capacitor, am I right now?

Comment: Coulombmeter measures electrostatic charge, not charge density in a current.

Answer (score 2):

Coulomb is used wen you have an object wich is charged. du you know what a capacitor is? Or did you do any electro static in class, like a charged sphere? Than you measure the charge in Coulomb. If you charge a capacitor with a current, you can use Q=I*t. If you want to measure the force between two charged objects you need to know there charge in Coulomb. In the context of electric current through bulbs or other resistors it will not be of much use, but the current over time will tell you how much charge went through your wires.